# Hide delete buttons in Typo3

Tags: permissions, acl, typo3

Somebody knows how to hide the trash buttons in the Web->List view in Typo3.

I need the BE users can create and edit records but not delete.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I developed an extension that permit me to have control of each action (icon) available on each table in the Web->List view.

I think anyone with these same needs could take advantage of it:

http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/hidelisticons

Have fun and write me if you have some problem using the extension.

Answer (score 0):

This is also possible with an extension I wrote a few years ago: http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/kb_modlist_actions